# OwnCloud Domain showing as localhost

Tags: reverse-proxy, docker-compose, owncloud

I have OwnCloud running behind an nginx reverse proxy on my server. I installed it via the docker-compose.yml, following these instructions: https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/admin_manual/installation/docker/

Everything works as I expected it besides one thing. The WebDav Link in the lower left corner shows as http://localhost:9001/... and not the acutal domain. Also, the Logout Button redirects to localhost. Everything else works fine.

Here is an image of my problem:

[image]

This is my .env Config-File:

```
OWNCLOUD_VERSION=10.12
OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=cloud.EXAMPLE.org
OWNCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=cloud.EXAMPLE.org
ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
ADMIN_PASSWORD=REDACTED
HTTP_PORT=8080
```

This is my reverse-Proxy:

```
server {
        server_name cloud.EXAMPLE.org;
        listen 443 ssl;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.de/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.de/privkey.pem;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself. I had to add the following configurations to my proxy. I didn't know OwnCloud decides the host by looking at the host in the HTTP Response. So the Host had to be changed in the proxy and also the extension for the used protocol (https):

```
server {
    server_name cloud.EXAMPLE.de;
    listen 443 ssl;
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:9001/;
        proxy_set_header    Host cloud.EXAMPLE.de;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;    
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.de/privkey.pem;
}
```